# Tiling rectangle with squares using Euclid's algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there a proof that tiling an n*m rectangle with squares using Euclid's algorithm (that is always choose the biggest square that fits in the remaining space) results in a minimum sum of the sizes (length of one side) of the resulting squares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call "sum of the sizes (length of one side)" as SS. And we assume that $m < n$ as for a square all is clear.

1. It's not hard to prove that SS(m,n) of euclidean algo is $m + n - gcd(m,n)$
2. We are to prove that it's the minimum of SS(m,n). We'll succeed in it if we prove that the biggest size of tiles for optimum tiling is $m$.
3. If it's not true we can assign 4 distinctive squares for every corner correspondingly.
4. Let's now count the perimeter of the rectangle. We consider only those squares which are adjacent to the border:

$$2(m+n) = \sum_{agjacent}l_i + \sum_{corner}l_j,$$

last sum contains the sizes of 4 squares assigned to the corners. Ok, then we get:

$$2(m+n) \le \sum_{all~ squares}l_i + \sum_{corner}l_j \le \sum_{all ~squares}l_i + 2m, $$

as "corneric" squares are paired and every pair have total size $\le m$

$$\sum_{all~ squares}l_i \ge 2n \ge n+m-gcd(n.m).$$

The covering is not optimal. Contradiction.

Comment: Correction: $2(m+n) = \sum_{\textrm{adjacent}}{l_i} + 2\sum_{\textrm{corner}}{l_j}$, since each corner touches two sides.

Comment: @augurar, "corneric" squares gives two sides to the calculation - one side is considered by "adjacent"-sum, the second - by "corner"-sum

Comment: Ah, I thought adjacent excluded the corners.

Comment: And the tile with the biggest size needs to to occupy two of the corners, or in other words to start as far left or right as possible, correct?

Comment: You can simplify the last two steps by considering just the two long sides.  Then you get $\sum_{\textrm{all}}{l_i} \geq 2n > n + m - \gcd(m, n)$ without having to consider the corners specially.

Comment: So what you proved is that in order to get an optimal covering of the rectangle, at least one square needs to be of size m (= the smallest of the two sides of the rectangle). Now we need to decide the best position for one of these squares. I think the best place is as at one of the ends of the rectangle. After placing this square, we repeat the procedure for the remaining rectangle. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @user42768 If you have a tiling with some size-$m$ squares, you can always rearrange it such that all the size-$m$ squares are at one end, without changing any of the sizes.

Comment: @augurar, yes, you're right. I miss such improvement

Comment: @user42768, yes, you're right. Moreover, we don't need to know the best place for m-square. We are just to apply mathematical induction for the remained part of rectangle after placing square at any position

Comment: But what if for example we have an initial rectangle with n=5 and m=3. And I decide to put a square of dimension 3 "in the middle" of the rectangle. This is not the best position (total sum of 9), because if I had put it at the left of the rectangle the total sum would have been 7.

Comment: But one observation is that wherever I decide to put it, the sum of the sizes is the same if I move the rectangle to the right or left. So placing it from the start at one of the extremes assures me that I can reach the minimum sum.

Comment: @user42768, ah, you are right. There we should prove that placing square at the center can not improve the result. And it demands: $(n-a,m)+(a,m) \le m + (n,m)$ for every possible natural $a$.

Comment: Why is my proof not enough? Suppose that I get the minimum sum if I put the biggest square somewhere in the middle. But moving it to one of the extremes, the sum remains the same. Is something wrong?

Comment: @user42768, you're right again :) it seems that my purpose today is to complicate all solutions)

Comment: Thank you very much, @restrest, without your idea I would have been stuck. Have a nice day!